# How to enable Windows 2003 as a WebDAV client?

Tags: windows-server-2003, webdav

I have written a program that uses webDAV to download documents from a sharepoint server. It works well with client OS (XP, Vista, 7) but it doesn't on the 2003 server it's supposed to work.

How can I enable WebDAV **client** (not server) on Windows server 2003 x86 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Server 2003 Web Folders (WebDAV client) is not installed by default. You can install it from Microsoft website: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15123

Note that this will install Web Folders extension. In case you wish to use Map Network Drive wizard (mini-redirector, another WebDAV client) follow this steps:

1. Make sure WebClient service is running. Open Services snap-in and find WebClient service. On Windows Server 2003 this service is disabled by default. If the service is disabled open WebClient Properties dialog and on General tab set Startup Type to Automatic. Restart the computer.
2. Your WebDAV server must be located on a default port 80. Map Network Drive wizard will fail to connect to any ports other than 80 displaying “The network path http://server/folder/ could not be found” message. Map Network Drive feature does not support SSL / HTTPS connections.
3. Your WebDAV server must accept anonymous connections or use Integrated Windows Authentication. Map Network Drive will fail to connect to WebDAV servers using Basic or Digest authentication. Use NTLM or Kerberos instead.
4. Connect to a folder on a WebDAV server rather than to the site root. The Map Network Drive wizard on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 will fail to connect to URLs such as http://server/. Instead specify an existing folder: http://server/folder/.

Comment: I'll accept that answer but the problem has long been solved. The issue wasn't actually linked to WebDAV but to the way the remote party had set it up. Specifically, it works better if you don't place your WebDAV server behind an SSl accelerator and use a self-signed SSL cert.

Answer (score 1):

The WebDAV client should be installed on all Windows since Windows 2000. Probably the service is not on by default for server platforms. Check if the WebClient service is running.

Comment: no, it is not installed on Windows 2008 Server. You must install Desktop Experience to enable it.